# Laravel 7 Nullable Validation Not Working ( All Solution Applied )

Tags: laravel

Laravel Nullable is not working, i try everything but it still not working. Please Look My Code..

Controller :-

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Pop;

class PopController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        return view('test2');
    }

    public function create(Request $request){

        $formvalidtion = $request->validate([
            'usercode' => ['nullable', 'required'],
        ]);

        return "<h1>SUCCESS</h1>";
    }

}
```

Model :-

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Pop extends Model
{
    protected $timestamps = false;
    protected $fillable = ['usercode'];
}
```

Migration :-

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreatePopsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('pops', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->integer('usercode')->nullable();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('pops');
    }
}
```

Route :-

```
route::get('test', 'PopController@index');

route::post('testcheck', 'PopController@create')->name('uc');
```

View :-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Nullable Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Test Nullable</h1>
    <form action="{{ route('uc') }}" method="POST">
        @csrf

        <input type="number" name="usercode" id="" placeholder="Enter User Code">
            @error('usercode')
                {{ $message }}
            @enderror
        <br>
        <input type="submit" >

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I spend 1 hour to find solution of but not get. some of youtube video in mentioned that datatype of field must be int and nullable . this also not working is there any solution available?

Comment: You didn't specify what you meant by its not working. Please help those who would answer your question with what you expected but didn't get.

Answer (score 4):

It's not right to use `nullable` and `required` validations rules together:

- `required`: The field under validation must be present in the input data and not empty.
- `nullable`: The field under validation may be null.
- `present`: The field under validation must be present in the input data but can be empty.
- `filled`: The field under validation must not be empty when it is present.
- `prohibited`: The field under validation must be empty or not present.
- `sometimes`: The field under validation will only be validated if it is present.
- `exclude`: The field under validation will be excluded from the request data returned by the `validate` and `validated` methods.

You may use `nullable` and `present` together:

```php
$formvalidtion = $request->validate([
    'usercode' => ['nullable', 'present'],
]);
```

Comment: I think using "it doesn't make sense" to address the OP's question is not respectable, at least this is the reason the question was asked. On the other hand, you're right, `required` rule makes `nullable` useless with the given example in the question.

Comment: @OluwatobiSamuelOmisakin You're right and I'm really sorry, I didn't know the negative effect of using this phrase, I'm not a native English speaker. I've edited my answer.

Comment: And for your humility.

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify what you mean with "not working" (i.e. what you expect, but what happens instead), but I'm assuming you mean that null values are not accepted by the validation.

That would be because the [`required` rule](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#rule-required) expects a value to be non-empty. So your `nullable` rule probably passes, but `required` fails.

If you want a value to be present, but not necessarily non-empty, you can use the [`present` rule](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#rule-present).

Comment: Can you please Give me Sample code so i can better understand.

Comment: You just replace `['nullable', 'required']` with `['present']`.

Comment: Example :- if user Enter name at time all validation applied and if user not enter name at time it should be allow null.